# Unable to send mail using CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, email, error-handling, codeigniter-3

Error: **Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

This is my email function

```
public function sendMail($emails) {
 $config = array(

            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'smtp_user' => 'no-reply@casrilanka.org', 
            'smtp_pass' => 'my_password', 
            'smtp_port' => '587',
            'smtp_crypto' => 'TLS'

        );
        $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
        $message = 'dsfsdfsdgndsgjdfgdsfjgkdfgkjdfghdfkghdfsbsdfgjklg';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('keesampath@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
        $this->email->to('sampathw.pipl@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
        $this->email->subject('Application submission');
        $this->email->message($message);
             $sss = $this->email->send();
if($sss){
echo 'ok';
}else{
echo  $this->email->print_debugger();
exit;
}

    }
```

Result :

```
220 KL1PR0601CA0020.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 23 Jun 2017 10:17:09 +0000 
    hello: 250-KL1PR0601CA0020.outlook.office365.com Hello [52.221.154.133]
    250-SIZE 157286400
    250-PIPELINING
    250-DSN
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-STARTTLS
    250-8BITMIME
    250-BINARYMIME
    250 CHUNKING
    Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
    Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
    User-Agent: CodeIgniter
    Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 10:17:09 +0000
    From: <keesampath@gmail.com>
    Return-Path: <keesampath@gmail.com>
    To: sampathw.pipl@gmail.com
    Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Application=20submissi?==?UTF-8?Q?on?=
    Reply-To: <keesampath@gmail.com>
    X-Sender: keesampath@gmail.com
    X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
    X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
    Message-ID: <594ceaa560fb1@gmail.com>
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

What would be the issue in my code. Thank you!

Comment: May be your server blocking outgoing and incoming request to authenticate with mail server.

Comment: @BhuneshSatpada can I check is server blocking outgoing and incoming request?

Comment: first check `mail('to','subject','body');` is it working and sent mail.

Comment: you can check port status using `fsockopen`

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Why would office365.com allow you to relay mail for a gmail user?